# Launch persistent context from current directory in playwright

Tags: python, directory, playwright, playwright-python

I'm using this code I found on this [page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69255853/start-playwright-driver-session-but-not-incognito) to save browser context after running the code:

```
user_dir = '/tmp/playwright'

with sync_playwright() as p:
  browser = p.chromium.launch_persistent_context(user_dir, headless=False)
  page = browser.new_page()
```

But when I try to change the directory from the `/tmp/playwright` folder, which is created in `C:`, to the current folder where I'm running the code (`user_dir = './tmp/playwright'`), the two folders are created but the playwright folder has nothing inside!
Does anyone know how to solve it? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Playwright does not play well with relative paths, use `os.getcwd()` instead. Also, note that you don't need to ensure that directories exist, playwright creates them automatically if they don't.

```
from playwright.sync_api import sync_playwright
import os

user_dir = 'tmp/playwright'
user_dir = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), user_dir)

with sync_playwright() as p:
    browser = p.chromium.launch_persistent_context(user_dir, headless=False)
    page = browser.new_page()
    page.goto('https://playwright.dev/python', wait_until='domcontentloaded')
```

Comment: `page = browser.new_page()` launches a new tab. Any idea to prevent two tabs?

Answer (score -1):

page = browser.pages[0] #first tab of browser